# Why does this Ajax render lose the bootstrap column width as set in a section tag?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ajax function reloading an element on the clock of a button, all reloads is fine, including all styles and the table that the objects is rendered within, except that upon js ajax render the rendered element loses it's bootstrap `col-md-4` class.

Top of _quote.html.erb partial;

```
<section id="quote" class="col-md-4 text-center">
```

button element in show.html.erb;

```
<button id="ReloadButton", data-remote='true' >Reload</button>
```

show.js.erb;

```
$("#quote").html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'quote') %>');
```

All other styles seem to be rendering just fine, inc other bootstrap defined styles.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: looks like you are loading the same element inside itself

Comment: You are setting the *contents* of the `#quote` element. You are *not* replacing the entire element, although that is what you seem to be expecting.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, pls excuse the js amateur'ness, is to reload the Quote instance's data within the rendered html, via ajax server request, not http reload. Would there be a better way to do so rather than my hacking above? (when clicking ReloadButton with my code, the whole #quote element reloads but without the col-md-4 styling).

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved through moving the `#quote` class div wrapper out from the _quote partial and into the `show.html.erb` template.